# What name Google Navigation package name and how to build intent?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use PackageManager to detect if Google navigation installed on a phone. If I use "URI = google.navigation" it doesn't find it.

What is the proper name for this package?

Also, I found sample on how to call google navigation with intent but I didn't find how to format full address with Address/city/state/zip. Any samples around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the US this works ...

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=housenumber+street+city+state+zip+country");

Spaces are ok between the + symbol